# What is the mean of rate of change of a function with respect to the domain of some other function, as in: $\frac{dFz}{dy}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

While studying 'curl' I came accross these terms:

[image]

Here, I don't understand the meaning of $\frac{dFz}{dy}$. Fz is a function of 'z', so what is the meaning of rate of change of Fz with respect to 'y'?

I understand differentiation as the rate of change of value of a function with respect to a change in the value of its domain. But 'y' here, is not the domain of 'Fz'. If it is, then what is the meaning of all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_z$ is not (necessarily) a function of $z$.  Notationally if $F$ was a function of z we would write $F(z)$, not $F_z$.

What is meant is that $F$ is a "vector field".  That is, $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ is a function which assigns a vector to every position in 3-space.  So $F_x$, $F_y$ and $F_z$ refer to the x, y and z-coordinates of $\vec{F}$ at any location.

Any coordinate of $F$ could be a function of any position coordinate (or of all three).